# Change the integer value with document.write()

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML :

```
 <beanRepresentation>
     <beanRepId>222</beanRepId>
     <beanRepName>Bean 1</beanRepName>
     <topY>10</topY>
     <leftX>10</leftX>
     <height>10</height>
     <width>10</width>
 </beanRepresentation>
```

This line gets the value of the topY:

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("topY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

This would give me a 10, but I want a 20, I tried to

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("topY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +10);
```

but it did not work, it gave me 1010 instead. what can do I do manipulate the number?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work?"  What did it actually do?  I suspect that you got something like `1010` as a result, because nodeValue is a string, not a number.

Comment: Well, there you go.  Javascript saw that `nodeValue` was a string, so it cast your number to a string, and mashed them together.  To get real math, you have to convert `nodeValue` to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `nodeValue` is a string (see, e.g., [MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue)), so you're performing string concatenation instead of an addition. You should convert the result to a number before:

```
document.write( parseInt( x[i].getElementsByTagName("topY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, 10)  + 10);
```

Anyway, I recommend you read the answers on this question: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1169798)